# Use of to-infinitives/present participles that describe a noun

Tags: present-participles, to-infinitive

My colleague at work keeps using to-infinitives and present participles that describe a noun in ways that I think are wrong. But I am not 100% sure if they are wrong and why.

1. He says, "PFC converting AC into DC voltage" to mean "PFC that converts AC into DC voltage".
2. He also says  "A function to change user password" to mean "a user password change function".

What I think is:

1. if you say "PFC converting AC into DC voltage", it means "PFC which *is converting* AC in to DC voltage," and
2. "A function to change user password" just doesn't make sense and it should be corrected to "a function of changing user password" or "a user password change function."

How I understand the to-infinitive is, that the noun described should be the direct object of the verb. So, if you say 'a book to read', 'a book' is the direct object of the verb 'read'. But you say 'a song to listen to' because you listen to a song but not 'listen a song' and 'a song' is not a direct object of 'listen'. If you say 'a function to change' doesn't that mean that 'you change a function.'?

Can someone help me please.

Comment: A lot depends on context. You might be justified with the PFC example but there may be some leeway with the second. Can you post more context? Full sentences at minimum, please. (Consider *sweet day* - without context, you can't tell whether it's the day for sweets or whether it's a very nice day. Maybe even both!)

Comment: The PFC example is among a list of devices that describes what each device does. We have to say "1. A is a device which does this. 2. B is a device which does this." The user password example is a list of functions that describes what each function does. And we have to say "1. A function used to do A. 2. A function used to do B."

Comment: If they’re just bullet points, I don’t see the problem with the *password* example. It even follows the template wording that you provided.

Comment: How I understand the to-infinitive is, that the noun described should be the direct object of the verb. So, if you say a book to read, 'a book' is the direct object of the verb 'read'. But you say 'a song to listen to' because you listen to a song but not 'listen a song' and 'a song' is not a direct object of 'listen'. If you say 'a function to change' doesn't that mean that 'you change a function.'?

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, these are both fine. Stylistically, we can't tell without more context.  If they're part of a list, the most important element of style is to ensure as much consistency as practical among the elements of the list. For example, either put a complete sentence for every element of the list, or for none of them.

"A function to change user password" is fine because the noun "function" can accept a to-infinitive complement explaining what the function allows. "A user password change function" is okay but slightly awkward due to collocating too many nouns. "A function of changing user password" means something different, because "function of" is generally used when function [means](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/function) "a relation where one thing is dependent on another for its existence, value, or significance."

If I understand the term "PFC" correctly, it doesn't refer to a device which converts power but rather to a quality of such devices or such conversion [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_factor#Power_factor_correction_(PFC)_in_non-linear_loads), [[2]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2215098617316737). As I understand it, then, it's not correct to say "PFC that converts AC into DC voltage" and probably not correct to say "PFC converting AC into DC voltage" either. Instead you would have to say something like "PFC conversion of AC into DC voltage".

Comment: 1. food to eat/book to read
2. function to change password/plan to lose weight/first man to reach South Pole

Can you explain how 1 and 2 are different grammatically?

Answer (score 0):

Supplementing Paul's good answer...

OP comments:

> the noun described should be the direct object of the verb

and

> 1. food to eat/book to read 2. function to change password/plan to lose weight/first man to reach South Pole Can you explain how 1 and 2
>      are different grammatically?

The noun complemented by the infinitive does not have to be the direct object of the verb.  Consider the following:

> They had food to eat.
>
> Here's a function to change background color.
>
> Where's the door to enter the attic?
>
> This food is to be eaten; it is not to be thrown around the cafeteria.

The food is for eating. That is its purpose.  The function does something, it changes the color of the background. That is its purpose. The door permits or allows someone to do something, enter the attic. That is its purpose.

But these things complemented by the infinitive phrase are not all "actors" or active agents in the fulfillment of their purpose. Nor are they always the passive recipient of the action. The food has something happen to it. It gets eaten. The function does something to something else; it changes something. The door allows someone else to do something.

Answer (score 0):

The *PFC* example isn't using [present participles](https://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/participlepresent.html) wrongly. However, unless the context allows it, there should be something between the noun PFC and its definition/description. For example:

- PFC: for converting AC into DC voltage

The *function* example looks fine as is. Your objection is that in the construct *a (noun) to (verb)* such as "a book to read", the verb should always be interpreted as applying to the preceding noun. However, that is not always the case. Consider a restaurant setting, where you've ordered a steak. You can say that you were provided:

- a steak to eat; and
- a knife to cut

The "steak to eat" part conforms to your 'verb applies to noun' rule (you eat the steak). However, the "knife to cut" part doesn't - you don't cut the knife (you use the knife to cut the *steak*). The second pattern applies to your colleague's *function* sentence.  The following definition clarifies the situation - the 'verb' part relates to the purpose or function of the noun, but it is not necessarily an action performed on the 'noun'.

> **to** *infinitive marker*
>   1.7 After a noun, indicating its function or purpose.
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/to)